# Can 'this' ever not be an object?

Tags: javascript

Just got asked this in an interview: can this function ever not return 'object'?

```
function foo() { return typeof this; }
```

To which I said I wasn't sure but guessed

```
foo.bind(undefined)()
```

would probably return `'undefined'`. But testing it at home in my console that doesn't work.

Comment: `function bar() {}`; `foo.call(bar)`;

Comment: @FrankModica If you have an answer, please put it in the answer section. This area is for suggesting changes to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In strict mode, `this` will *not* be coerced to an object:

```js
'use strict';
function foo() { return typeof this; }

console.log(foo.call('abc'));
console.log(foo.call(5));
```

(but this is a *really really weird* thing to try to do, I would hope never to see it in serious code)

`this` can also be `undefined` in strict mode if there's no calling context:

```js
'use strict';
function foo() { return typeof this; }

console.log(foo());
```

In sloppy mode, it appears that functions don't get coerced to objects (though primitives *do*):

```js
function foo() { return typeof this; }

console.log(foo.call(() => 'abc'));
```